# Kaк распараллеливаются вычисления на GPU с помощью OpenCL

Tags: c, opencl

У меня есть блок с 3 функциями, который запускается в параллельных потоках. Необходимо этот блок запустить на 1000 потоках на видеокарте. Должен ли я в функции, которую передаю на видеокарту прописать сам создание потоков или же видеокарта данную функцию вычисляет только раз, сколько я запишу при передаче функции потоков?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Видеокарта - это и есть потоковый процессор. Никакие потоки создавать **НЕ** надо. Вы пишете *Kernel* - функцию на **C99**, которая будет вычисляться для конкретного потока; там у вас будут внутри **3 спец. функции**. Да хоть 103: Kernel можно на модули разбить!! Номер потока, с которым работает Kernel, узнаёте вызовом функции **int i = get_global_id(0)** внутри него. В зависимости от номера потока - разные действия внутри Kernel. Ну как в обычном цикле по индексу **i**. ;) Размер этого самого цикла (**1000**) задаётся на хосте - параметр **global_work_size** функции **clEnqueueNDRangeKernel**. После запуска Kernel'а с хоста - **clEnqueueNDRangeKernel** - цикл сам закрутится. Всё! В принципе, может быть несколько разных Kernel, которые можно запускать последовательно в цикле *уже на хосте*. Кстати, при асинхронных вызовах можно даже в параллель запускать - фишка **OpenCL**, которой нет у **CUDA**.